# Since the formula for curvature is $\frac{1}{R}$, why can't we just find curvature of say: $r=3+2\cos{\theta}$, where $\theta=0$ by substituting?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, curvature

The polar function gives the radius, why do we still need to use the convoluted curve formula to solve it? Shouldn't K=$\frac{1}{R}=\frac{1}{3+2\cos{0}}=\frac{1}{5}$? Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Because $R$ isn't the same thing as $r$.

Comment: I see, is it because $\frac{1}{R}=K$, that R has to be radius of a circle? where r(t) is the length of origin to that point in the curve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The radius of curvature at a point does not have anything to do with the distance from the origin.

For a start, the circle with the same radius of curvature as the function is not necessarily centered at the origin. Furthermore, there are infinitely many circles passing through the origin and $(r, \theta) = (5, 0)$: you need a third point to determine the unique circle with the right radius of curvature.

Comment: Any, origin? Like a center of the circle?

I learned that r is just the magnitude of the vector that draws the curve $r(t)$, is that not right?.... Seems to align with Wiki... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system

Comment: Yep, the vector you are measuring is from the origin.